# android apps on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, android

Is it possible to run APK's on 17.10? I saw the other posts but they were no where near helpful! I don't know what that Twerk application was but the link did not work. Is there anyway to use an android application on ubuntu 17.10? things like bluestacks and whatnot do not work on wine, and all the android emulators like ANbox don't work in 17.10 gnome, wayland or Xorg.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run some android apps through google chrome. There's a pretty good chance it'll work on chromium as well if you have that installed.

Copy and paste each line into the terminal to install it.

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```